# Why is Fiddler doing a GET when I set it to POST

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

When I try to call my WEB API from Fiddler it calls using GET even though I set Fiddler to use POST.

NOTE: All my GET API methods are working fine.

```
POST   http://www.myapisite.com/api/UserAccounts/CreateAccount

[Header] User-Agent: 
Fiddler Host: www.myapisite.com 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: 453

[Request Body]
{
   "user_id": "1",
   "store_id": "1",
   "merchant_id": "1"
}
```

My WEB API method signature:

```
    [ValidateModelState]
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    [Route("api/UserAccounts/CreateAccount")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "mymvcsite.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult CreateAccont(
        [FromBody]AccountHolderDto accountHolderDto)
    {
       ... 
    }
```

AccountHolderDto is simply a class with public properties (user_id, store_id, merchant_id)

Any help much appreciated! - This has had me baffled the entire day

Comment: can you also add the code of the method that is actually getting called ?

Comment: @RaviA I would think the method signature of what's getting called is sufficient, I cannot add the code, it's proprietary.  And why would the internal code of the method have anything to do with my Fiddler doing a GET instead of a POST?

Comment: No my question was to post the signature of the Get method that is being executed for the above call.Why do you feel fiddler is doing a Get?

Comment: @RaviA Because after I Execute it, I click on Headers in Fiddler and get this:
[Request Headers]
GET /api/UserAccounts/CreateAccount HTTP/1.1
[Response Headers]
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 0):

Damn!, I removed the "www" prefix of the uri and it works now
From this:
http://www.myapisite.com/api/UserAccounts/CreateAccount
To this:
http://myapisite.com/api/UserAccounts/CreateAccount

Unbelievable the smallest things cause so much pain